# Why is my displayed reputation daily change lower than it actually is?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

Is there a bug in the daily total for the new reputation tab - https://stackoverflow.com/users/373321/stuart?tab=reputation

e.g. this is  mine currently shows 70... but should it be 90?

```
 70  Today
+20  33 secs ago  2 votes  c# Date component bug or am i missing something?
+20  1 hour ago   2 votes  how to code Windows phone 7 UI only programatically (in .cs file)without using designer
+10  18 mins ago  upvote   What is the equivalent of Delphi “ZeroMemory” in C#?
+10  1 hour ago   upvote   C# how to format a value taken from text box?
+10  1 hour ago   upvote   Generic interface in C#
+10  1 hour ago   upvote   Code that return True if only one or two of three params are true
+10  6 hours ago  upvote   Grid events - send data to user when he clicks the grid
```

Here's a second example:
[image: why does the day total not end in a 5?]

Disclaimer - I've just looked through 5 "Related Questions" - but couldn't spot any reporting this bug - but I stopped after looking at 5!

Comment: No repro, I see +30+20+10+10+10+10+10 = 100 for you right now.

Comment: Those darned users with their upvoting. But I copied and pasted what it was showing.

Comment: Another example live right now - I'm guessing there is just some timing issue between the total and itemised displays?

Comment: I'm seeing 165 instead of 150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having posted a couple of examples now - and seen the responses/comments a few minutes later - it looks like this is just a timing issue - the two displays are "eventually consistent".

Comment: Heh, file another one under 'caching' :)